# Am new to to Protractor testing, Could you please advise me how to write script for login webpage and go to next page

Tags: testing, protractor

Am new to Protractor testing, am writing the script for login page and need to go to next page. Could you please advise me on this how to proceed this

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines on How To Ask questions. Provide some example code of what you have tried. People will help if they see you have made an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Refer https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor-example to get working example project with protractor.